# Storing a PHP loop as a string in a variable

Tags: php, string, variables, loops

I have a problem storing a PHP loop in a variable.

The loop is like this:

```
for( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {

    echo $i . ' - ';

}
```

for this it's OK for an `echo` or `print` as it will produce:

> 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 -

now I want to store the whole loop in a variable like `$my_var` which means:

```
echo $my_var;
```

which will produce:

> 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9 - 10 -

the whole idea is that I want to make the loop, store it as a string in a variable `$my_var`, than use it later in my script.

Comment: Doesn't `$my_var .= $i.'-'` in the loop code work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply append the new string to the old one.

```
$str = '';

for( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
    $str .= $i . ' - ';    
}

echo $str;
```

Alternatively, you could do...

```
$str = implode(range(1, 10), ' - ') . ' - ';
```

...or even...

```
$str = implode(array_merge(range(1, 10), array(' ')), ' - ');
```

Comment: @med Welcome to programming :)

Comment: I have 4 years of php development and always wandered about the .= and it came the time that I finally understood it. so it is used to append! thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 Are your alternative solutions examples of functional programming?

Comment: @medk: You said: "Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I need." A good follow-up to that sentence would be a click on the "Accepted" check.

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_var = '';
for( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {

    $my_var .= $i' - ';

}
echo $my_var;
```

**Hope it will work**